# SQLite in vb 2010

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

I have, for over a month, tried in vain to resolve this. I am using SQLite and trying to write a simple check to see if i can connect to the database. I found some code here that was supposed to do just that.

```
    Public Function ConnExist(strDB) As Boolean
    Dim SQLconnect As New SQLite.SQLiteConnection()

    Try
        Using Query As New SQLiteCommand()
            SQLconnect.ConnectionString = "DataSource=" & strDB & ";Version=3;New=False;Compress=True;"
            SQLconnect.Open()

            With Query
                .Connection = SQLconnect
                .CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tbltest"
            End With

            Query.ExecuteNonQuery()
            SQLconnect.Close()
        End Using
        'SQLconnect.ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & strDB & ";Version=3;New=False"
        'SQLconnect.Open()
        'SQLconnect.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        'Return False
    End Try

    Return True
End Function
```

I know the database is at the location specified. On the `SQLconnect.Open()` part it errors out and tells me datasource cannot be empty. I opened the database using DB Browser and it is not corrupt. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What the error means is that the DataSource portion of the connection string cannot be empty ("").  If the code that calls that function doesnt pass the valid DS in `strDB` you will get that error.  Also turn on Option Strict; visit   http://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlite/ and you connection should also be in a `Using` block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Public Function ConnExist(strDB) As Boolean
    Dim cs As String
    Dim cnn As New SQLiteConnection
    Dim cmd As New SQLiteCommand

    cs = "Data Source=" & strDB & ";Version=3;New=False;"

    If (IO.File.Exists(strDB)) Then
        cnn = New SQLiteConnection(cs)
        Try
            cnn.Open()
            cmd = cnn.CreateCommand()
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tblSettings"
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cnn.Close()
            cmd.Dispose()
            cnn.Dispose()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return False
            Exit Function
        End Try
    Else
        Return False
        Exit Function
    End If

    Return True

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I build my connection string for SQLite.

```
Dim constr As String = "Data Source=""" & FullFilePath & """;Pooling=true;FailIfMissing=false"
```

Think you are just missing the Double Quotes around the path.

Comment: The double quotes I believe is for VBA. I figured it out finally. I'll provide the function that I figured below. Thanks for the response though.